# Why can't I use U::from with T: Into<U> constraint?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I want to have a simple types conversions and I think the code should look like this:

```rust
struct Celsius(f64);
struct Fahrenheit(f64);

impl From<Celsius> for Fahrenheit {
    fn from(c: Celsius) -> Self {
        Fahrenheit(c.0 * 9. / 5. + 32.)
    }
}

impl From<Fahrenheit> for Celsius {
    fn from(f: Fahrenheit) -> Self {
        Celsius((f.0 - 32.) * 5. / 9.)
    }
}

fn danger_of_freezing<T: Into<Celsius>>(temp: T) -> bool {
    let celsius = Celsius::from(temp);
    celsius.0 < 0.0
}

fn main() {
    danger_of_freezing(Celsius(20.0));
    danger_of_freezing(Fahrenheit(68.0));
}
```

But compiler give me this:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Celsius: From<T>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:17:33
   |
17 |     let celsius = Celsius::from(temp);
   |                   ------------- ^^^^ the trait `From<T>` is not implemented for `Celsius`
   |                   |
   |                   required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
help: consider introducing a `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
   |
16 | fn danger_of_freezing<T: Into<Celsius>>(temp: T) -> bool where Celsius: From<T> {
   |                                                          ++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I dont understand where is the problem in my code. I know that `From` and `Into` traits are related, and if I implement `From`, `Into` will be implemented automatically, but I dont understand why `Celsius` should be generic type.

Maybe this code will be more idiomatic (at least this code compiles):

```rust
fn danger_of_freezing<T: Into<Celsius>>(temp: T) -> bool {
    let celsius: Celsius = temp.into();
    celsius.0 < 0.0
}
```

But still why first variant doesn't work?

Comment: *"I dont understand why `Celsius` should be generic type"* - `where Celsius: From<T>` does not require `Celsius` to be generic. Concrete types can have constraints specified in `where` clauses (especially where the constraint has a generic involved).

Comment: I didn't know where could be used in such a context, thx. Is declaring a function in my code the same as this: `fn danger_of_freezing<T>(temp: T) -> bool where Celsius: From<T>`  or are there pitfalls here?

Comment: If you wanted to keep using `Celsius::from`, then yes you could do that and get your function working. Though as I mentioned in my answer, it is more idiomatic to use `Into` in this scenario (since it is marginally more accommodating), but it is pretty rare for it to actually make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that anything implementing `From` has a reflexive `Into` implementation provided automatically, which means any `From` conversion can use `.into()`, but *the reverse is not true*; a type may implement `Into` and not have the reflexive `From` implementation.

It is idiomatic to use `Into` (instead of `From`) for function parameters, so you should use `.into()` within the function body like your last code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is why `Celsius::from(temp)` gives an error...

In your code there are exactly two method implementations for `Celsius::from`

1. `Celsius::from(temp: Fahrenheit)` which you provided
2. `Celsius::from(temp: Celsius)` which is generic because `From`is reflexive.

So this is valid:

```
Celsius::from(Celsius(1.));
Celsius::from(Fahrenheit(1.));
```

And any other types are not, for example the generic type `T`.